# How do I convert shape key animations to skeletal based animations?

Tags: animation, rigging, shape-keys

Good day, I was wondering if there was any way to convert vertex animations such as shape key animations to skeletal based animations. I am trying to do this due to the fact that the game engine that I am working in does not support vertex animations.